# Debug exe in VS from commandline

Tags: c#, debugging

I need to debug an old exe that was created in bin/Debug to see why it is now failing.

The exe needs an argument, so I cannot ATTACH to process after exe has started, because it is probably just after IntializeComponenet() of form that error occurs.

Is there a way to run an exe with an argument from command line or VS?

```
MyApp.exe MyArgumentstring
```

Comment: You can run the exe but can not debug it.

Comment: if you have the original source code you can debug otherwise not possible.

Comment: Well I can attach to the process, but I need to run again from the beginning. Either Main() or Form()

Comment: You can pass arguments in the debug settings page. What you can't do, at least not without a debug build and a decompiler, is debug without the source code - or at least, you'll have to debug at the assembly level

Comment: You can do this with WinDbg - you can launch the app with arguments and debug before even the CLR starts to run your code.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen that looks a bit low level!

Comment: I have source code in my VisualSVN - is there a way I can use that? I know the revision that created the exe.